# shiny and ggvis force observe() to resolve before bind_shiny()

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have some hierarchical data of the form Parent(System) and Child(Group).  In shiny I have two sets of radio buttons, one for System and one for Group.  I use an observe() statement thusly to update the Group radio buttons to only be those which exist for the selected System:

```
observe({
  r_options <- list()
  groups <- unique(fulldata$group[fulldata$system=input$system])
  updateRadioButtons(session,"group","Group",choices=groups,selected=paste(groups[1]))
},priority=100)
```

Originally, I had just used renderPlot in my server.R file and it produced a vanilla R plot.  When I made a change to the System, an error `Error: dims [product 1] do not match the length of object [0]` would pop up in place of the graph for a moment and then it would be replaced by the new graph.

Now I'm trying to replace the graph with a ggvis plot, so the renderPlot has been replaced with a reactive (stored in the object vis) which culminates in the building of a ggvis plot and the last line:

```
vis %>% bind_shiny("mychart")
```

Now, the application crashes and the same error message is output to the console.
I've tried writing the code where the reactive stores the data needed for the graph and then calling the whole ggvis block outside of the reactive element ala:

```
fon = reactive({...})
fon %>%
  ggvis(~date,~value,stroke=~type) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  bind_shiny("mychart")
```

I don't know why this results in a spectacular failure versus a friendly note, but my main interest is in knowing how can I de-prioritize the last line(s) so it won't execute until after the observe statement is complete?  Or is there a better way to output ggvis when inputs reactively change?